# VueJS "_d3_hexbin__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__ is not a function"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js, vue-composition-api

I have a Vue 3 app that is supposed to take a database of Lat, Long coordinates and plot them over a map in a hexbin chart. I am using D3 for the chart, and I have been able to render the map, and some other charts, but I have not been able to get the hexbin to render because I keep getting the error `TypeError: _d3_hexbin__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__ is not a function`.

(I am using vanilla JS and Vue 3 composition API.)

Here is my import statement for D3 and D3-Hexbin:

```js
import * as d3 from "d3";
import * as d3hexbin from "d3-hexbin";

let hexbin = d3hexbin();
```

My implementation is in the Vue `onMounted` lifecycle hook as follows:

```js
  const hexW = 600,
    hexH = 700;

  const grid = d3
    .select("#hex")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", hexW)
    .attr("height", hexH)
    .append("g");
  const color = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 500]).range(["transparent", "red"]);

  const hex = hexbin().radius(9).extent([
    [0, 0],
    [hexW, hexH]
  ]);

  grid
    .append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", hexW)
    .attr("height", hexH);

  grid
    .append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(dataHexMap.values())
    .join("path")
    .attr("d", hex.hexagon())
    .attr("transform", (d) => `translate(${d.x}, ${d.y})`)
    .attr("fill", (d) => color(d.length))
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 0.1);
```

I have tried the responses given by Mike Bostock [here on the GitHub repo](https://github.com/d3/d3-hexbin/issues/16). I have also tried to import the function as a local library by downloading the code from [this link from the same repo](https://d3js.org/d3-hexbin.v0.2.min.js), importing it as `import * as d3hexbin from "../d3-hexbin";`

In addition, I have tried importing everything from the d3-hexbin file like this:

```js
import * as d3 from "d3-hexbin";
```

Which told me `TypeError: _d3_hexbin__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.select is not a function`.

I am at a loss. Again, I am using vanilla JS and Vue 3 composition API. And because I am not using TS, many of the Stack Overflow answers were unhelpful, or were tried with the above methods.

Thank you in advance for your help with this

EDIT: I my code is a derivation of the d3 v6 code on [D3 Graph Gallery](https://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/density2d_hexbin.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the hexagons to show up with this method:

Using either the local library method or using an import statement, assigned `hexbin` like this:

```js
let hexbin = d3hexbin.hexbin()
```

The hexagons now show up, arranged how I needed them to be.

Also, I changed `dataHexMap` to an array called `dataHexArr` with the same values, and fixed `.data(dataHexMap.values())` to say `.data(hex(dataHexArr))`.

There are still a handful of bugs I am trying to work through, but I finally found a solution to my original question, so I figured I would post it for future reference.